Combining multiple CSV files with varying indices into a single data frame
I have a series of files produced each day. Each line has 2 pieces of information city name and rainfall.  The file names are day of year.
For example, file D2024300  might have

London   0  
Paris   10 
Sydney  40 

But not each file has the same list of cities.  If the city is missing the assumption is it has 0 value.
I want to combine files into a single CSV file with each column being a date, e.g.:

Table  D300 D301 D302
London    0    6    0 
Paris    10   25    0 
Sydney   40   60    0 

I thought about the CSV module but it appears to need numeric indexes whereas I have character indices. I have tried dictionaries but adding extra cities on the fly did not work.

Please show us your code and the actual problem you are having with it.

The task is clear. At least show the code that reads these files. D{yyyy}{ddd}, where yyyy is the year, ddd is the day of the year. Is that true?

What's the naming convention for the output CSV file? Where are the input files? How do you decide which input files to read? In what way is your current code (that you forgot to add to your question) not working?

Did you try with Pandas? Do you have a full list of possible cities or some fancy small city could be added any day in the future?

Please define "relatively efficient". Relative to what?

So, assuming you have three CSV files in a ./data/ directory as you defined in your example, the code here should suffice. Note that D2024302.csv is empty.
First, you read in your CSVs (using Pandas here), and keep a record of the days and cities you've seen so far:
import itertools
import pathlib

import pandas as pd


dfs, days, cities = [], set(), set()
for file in pathlib.Path("data/").glob("*.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, names=["city", "count"])
    day = f"D{file.stem[-3:]}"
    df["day"] = day
    dfs.append(df)
    days.add(day)
    cities |= set(df["city"].unique())

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

This will produce a data frame that looks like this:




city
count
day




0
London
0
D300


1
Paris
10
D300


2
Sydney
40
D300


3
London
6
D301


4
Paris
25
D301


5
Sydney
60
D301



Now, you add on a full index of day-city pairs:
full_frame = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(cities, days)), columns=["city", "day"])
df = df.merge(full_frame, how="outer", on=["city", "day"])

Your data frame now looks like this:




city
count
day




0
London
0
D300


1
London
6
D301


2
London
nan
D302


3
Paris
10
D300


4
Paris
25
D301


5
Paris
nan
D302


6
Sydney
40
D300


7
Sydney
60
D301


8
Sydney
nan
D302



You can fill in the missing values using pd.Series.fillna():
df.loc[:, "count"] = df["count"].fillna(0)


Thank you all.  Whilst the use of Pandas looks interesting I have not used it.
I was able to make use of the function  update_data to achieve what I wanted
BUT I am going to take a good look the example with a dictionary - cause that is along the lines of what I initially tried and could not get to work,
Many Many thanks
BZ

@user3649104 I wonder what you mean by the update_data function. That's something new, isn't it?

There was answer where someone had written a user function "update_data" that seemed to work for me - which I was referring to.  Not sure where it is now

I'd suggest to use pandas in this case. With this library you can accomplish the task in two conceptual steps: concatenate the data and pivot the result:
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

source_dir = Path('/source/of/data')
file_pattern = 'D2024*'
data = [pd.read_csv(f, sep='\s+', names=['city', 'value'])   # make sure data hase 2 columns with fixed names
        .assign(date=f.stem)                                 # save the file name in date column
        for f in source_dir.glob(file_pattern)]
df = (pd.concat(data)                          # concatenate data
      .set_index(['city','date'])              # and apply one of the pivoting techniques  
      .unstack(fill_value=0)
      .droplevel(0, 'columns'))

Code for experiments:
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory

with TemporaryDirectory() as source_dir:
    source_dir = Path(source_dir)
    with open(source_dir/'D2024300', 'w') as f:
        f.write('Paris   10\nSydney  40')
    with open(source_dir/'D2024301', 'w') as f:
        f.write('London  6\nParis   25\nSydney  60')
    with open(source_dir/'D2024302', 'w') as f:
        f.write('Moscow 55\nLondon  17\nParis    5')
    
    source_dir = Path(source_dir)
    file_pattern = 'D2024*'
    data = [pd.read_csv(f, sep='\s+', names=['city', 'value']).assign(date=f.stem)
            for f in source_dir.glob(file_pattern)]
    df = (pd.concat(data)
          .set_index(['city','date'])
          .unstack(fill_value=0)
          .droplevel(0, 'columns'))

Check the result:
print(df)

# date    D2024300  D2024301  D2024302
# city                                
# London         0         6        17
# Moscow         0         0        55
# Paris         10        25         5
# Sydney        40        60         0

destination = 'destination.csv'
df.to_csv(destination)
with open(destination) as f:
    print(f.read())

# city,D2024300,D2024301,D2024302
# London,0,6,17
# Moscow,0,0,55
# Paris,10,25,5
# Sydney,40,60,0


Suppose we don't want to use Pandas, but only Python and its standard modules. In that case, I’d approach it in the following three steps:

Load the data as a dictionary with dates extracted from file names as keys and dictionaries of city: value pairs as values.
Transpose the data so that the output allows access to values as transposed[city][date] = value with zero as default value for missing (city, date) pairs.
Write this output as CSV rows.

Possible implementation:
files = [...]      # an iterable object with file names,
                   # e.g. Path(source_directory).glob('D2024*')

# Load data as a dictionary with file names as keys
data = {}
parse_date = lambda x: x[5:]       # adjust to your needs
for file_name in files:
    with open(file_name) as f:
        day = parse_date(file_name)
        data[day] = f.read().splitlines()

# Build a dictionary from the split pairs 'city value' 
data = {day: dict(record.split() for record in city_values) 
        for day, city_values in data.items()}

# Transpose data: data[day][city] == transposed[city][day] == value
DEFAULT_VALUE = 0
transposed = defaultdict(lambda: dict.fromkeys(data.keys(), DEFAULT_VALUE))
for day, city_data in data.items():
    for city, value in city_data.items():
        transposed[city][day] = value

# Save as csv
with open('destination.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['city', *data.keys()])
    writer.writerows([[city, *dates.values()] 
                      for city, dates in transposed.items()])

